# Is there a way to disable the address bar on a browser on page load

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I am creating a landing page for customer wifi, we already have a way of the page being the first to load, now I want to go one further. I want the customers to agree to our usage policy before they can continue, so basic stuff, create a page, add T&C's and a check box and an accept button, check to box click accept and you are on your way to internet awesomeness!

Except users could bypass this by changing the address in the address bar.
What I want to do is disable any address changes, thus disabling the address bar

Is it possible to do this using a simple javascript? Is there an easier way of solving this issue?

Comment: No, you cannot take control of peoples browsers and disallow them the choice to visit other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<html>
  <script for="window" event="onload">
      window.open('main.jsp',
      'Window',
      'width=800,height=600,resizable=0,status=0,toolbar=0');
      // Hack to bypass the confirm alert on window close.
      window.opener = window.top;
      window.open('', '_self', '');
      window.close();
  </script>
</html>
```

This opens a new window on *main.jsp* with reduced abilities and closes the launched window (which comes from *index.jsp*).

And - contrary to popular belief - the new window does **not** have an address bar. In fact it also doesn't have a close box either but you can change that.

P.S. - This might only work for IE.

Comment: Cheers OldCurmudgeon This seems as a good solution for me for the time being

Answer (score 2):

you cant lock the browser address bar, no.

normally they just route every page request, except from your domain, to your page until someone has accepted/verified

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript confirm box:

```
var result=confirm("Press a button!")
 if (result==true)
   {
   alert("You pressed OK!")
   }
 else
   {
   alert("You pressed Cancel!")
   }
 }
```

And make some condition..if the user presses ok then do something, else you can redirect him to some other page...though these alerts really interfere with UI experience..